# Prove: $a^2 \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial ^2x}=\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial ^2t}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $f,g$ functions of $C^2$ class and $a$ constant. Consider the function $u$ defined by $u(x,t)=f(x-at)+g(x+at)$.

Prove: $a^2 \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial ^2x}=\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial ^2t}$

As $f,g$ are function of $C^2$ class then $f$ and $g$ are derivative, we have:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=f'(x-at)+g'(x+at)$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-af'(x-at)+ag'(x+at)$

$\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial ^2x}=f''(x-at)+g''(x+at)$

$\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial ^2t}=a^2(f''(x-at)+g''(x+at))$

Then $a^2 \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial ^2x}=a^2(f''(x-at)+g''(x+at))=\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial ^2t}$

I have two doubts with this exercise.

1) We need the hypothesis of $C^2$ for make the partial derivative?

2) Is okay the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, you need the smoothness of $f$ and $g$ to take derivatives. If the derivative is understood in the distributional sense, the smoothness requirement of $f$ and $g$ becomes less stringent.

2) The proof is correct.